# Leakage current 2-pin usb-c charger

Tags: charger, usb-c, emi-filtering, laptop

since I began using a 2-prong usb-c charger, i have noticed a vibrating sensation when moving my hand over the metal body of my laptop. If i ground myself, the vibration gets stronger. If I use the three-pin barrel charger included with the laptop (with ground connection), the effect ceases. It seems that is leakage current produced by the usb-c charger because of the way it filters EMI (i am not an electrical engineer, please excuse the imprecise explanation). Apparently, the chassis gets a potential which is half so high as the input potential and "floats" there. If the charger is grounded, this current gets dumped through the extra pin.

As I understand, it should be harmless for me, but what about the things I connect my laptop to? Say, for example, I connect a grounded monitor to my laptop while charging with the aforementioned usb-c charger. Can it damage the port because of the discharge (potential difference)? I find it difficult to believe that that could be the case, since there are very few usb grounded chargers on the market... Asking just to have peace of mind.

Thanks in advance and excuse the noobness :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can do damage.

There is a capacitive coupling between mains side and isolated laptop side.

When there is charge stored on the capacitor and you connect a grounded thing to the laptop, the capacitance will discharge fast with large current. This usually causes no issues with good connectors that connect ground first via connector chassis, but some connectors are not like that, and the capacitor may discharge via supply or data pin, destroying the laptop or the other device.

I don't know which charger you have and what it is intended purpose or rating of electrical safety, but it may be best to only use it for charging things, and avoid using it when there is a need to connect laptop to other equipment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tested two 20W chargers from Apple (included with an iPad pro 11 and iphone 12 mini), as well as this charger: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Belkin-USB-C-Charger-GaN-WHT/dp/B089B8N9HB  . All of them exhibit the same behaviour. Could you recommend a charger which at least minimizes the effect? Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe a follow-up question: what would be, in your eyes, a "good connector"? Ports like usb or hdmi are standards, so they are all built in the same physical way. How can one then differenciate between good and bad connectors? I still find it difficult to believe that manufacturers chose to ignore such obvious phenomenon . The two pin chargers have become the standard. Like I said, it is really difficult to find a good 3-pin charger, and usually only 2-pin are included with the products one can buy.

Comment: @pietrodelta7 HDMI and USB should be hot-pluggable. In practice, I don't trust them if any device has 2-pin mains plug. I have damaged HDMI ports of devices that have 2-pin mains connections while plugging them in to other devices when they are plugged to mains, so this is the reason why almost all devices with 2-pin mains connections have a warning in their manual that they should be unplugged from mains before making connections to other devices.I have never had a 2-pin charger with any of laptop I have used at home or work. Only mobile phone chargers have been 2-pin so far.

Comment: Thanks for your insights! :)

Comment: Another follow up question. May I ask what kind of HDMI devices you damaged?